# Swift: How to define a fixed array of flexible String array

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, indexing, enums

I already have several arrays for strings. I want to add them to a list of arrays, so I can use a predefined (enum) index. The individual arrays are already in place, I only need to access them via index (fixed with enum or within a loop with index from enum type). So there should be no copy of the strings within the array, only a reference to the array itself.

I already have this in mind:

```
enum TypeOfArray: Int {
        case Src = 0, Dest, SrcCache, DstCache, N
    }

    var srcFolders : [String] = [] 
    var dstFolders : [String] = []
    var srcFoldersCache : [String] = [] 
    var dstFoldersCache : [String] = []

    var allFolders: [[String]] = []
```

Then I want to initilaze the main array by assigning each of the individual arrays. But this is rejected by the compiler: ("Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String]]' with an index of type 'TypeArray'")

```
allFolders[TypeOfArray.Src] = srcFolders
```

I don't know if this "typesave" index is even possible. 
Can I use a fixed index range 0..N when defining for optimizing memory or speed?
Any ideas?

Comment: Why not create a dictionary where a key would be your enum and value a string array ?

Comment: Thank you, a great idea and the solution of this problem.

Comment: That comment was before I tried it out. :-)

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary would be a good solution for this:

```
var dict = [TypeOfArray:[String]]()
dict[TypeOfArray.Src] = srcFolders
```

Comment: That doesn't seems to work. :-( It copies the actual content to the dictionary, but when srcFolders is changed, that doesn't have an effect on the item in the dictionary. So that seems not to be a refernece but a value copy. What do I have to change?

Comment: Of course it does that, Arrays, Strings and Dictionaries are all Value types in Swift

Comment: Ok, but as described in the top <<So there should be no copy of the strings within the array, only a reference to the array itself.>> I need a different approach. I read about wrappers, but is it realy neccessary to generate new classes only to assign the adress of the array (&srcFolders in old C-style)?

Answer (score 1):

### Singleton

If you want to share the content of your arrays, an you want the updates to be reflected in your code, you can use a Singleton

```
final class ImageNameManager {
    static let sharedInstance = ImageNameManager()
    var srcFolders: [String]
    var dstFolders: [String]
    var srcFoldersCache: [String]
    var dstFoldersCache: [String]

    private init() {
        // populate: srcFolders, dstFolders, srcFoldersCache, dstFoldersCache
        srcFolders = []
        dstFolders = []
        srcFoldersCache = []
        dstFoldersCache = []
    }

    enum ImageType: Int {
        case Src = 0, Dest, SrcCache, DstCache
    }

    func imageNames(imageType: ImageType) -> [String] {
        switch imageType {
        case .Src: return srcFolders
        case .Dest: return dstFolders
        case .SrcCache: return srcFoldersCache
        case .DstCache: return dstFoldersCache
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage

Now you can populate one of your array

```
ImageNameManager.sharedInstance.dstFolders.append("Hello")
```

and receives the new data in another section of your code

```
let dstFolders = ImageNameManager.sharedInstance.imageNames(.Dest)
// ["Hello"]
```

### Update

In order to share the same array across your app you cal also use this code

```
final class ImageNameManager {
    static let sharedInstance = ImageNameManager()
    var srcFolders: [String] = []
    var dstFolders: [String] = []
    var srcFoldersCache: [String] = []
    var dstFoldersCache: [String] = []
}
```

Now alway reference it the array with this code `ImageNameManager.sharedInstance.dstFolders`, look

```
ImageNameManager.sharedInstance.dstFolders.append("Hello")
ImageNameManager.sharedInstance.dstFolders.append("World")
ImageNameManager.sharedInstance.dstFolders // ["Hello", "World"]
```

Comment: Great. I just had an similar attempt. But when using imageNames returning e.g. srcFolders it gets a copy of srcFolders. Correct? And when I change it, srcFolders is not updated. (at least within my test cases.) I need to get the reference with imageNames(Src) and do some changes to the basic array.

Comment: @Peter71: I added an update to my answer, please check it out

Comment: Maybe I wasn't able to explain it exactly. I want to iterate over the 4 arrays, e.g. imageNames[0], imageNames[1] ... => I'm not able to access always the source array by name. And when accessing, I need to update them. Not a local copy, but the source array. In C it would be easyly done by the & operator used for the source arrays. The dictionary would be a 4 item large pointer array.